# What do you call someone who's fascinated by machines?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, vocabulary

See people who are fascinated by machines like computers, cars, bikes, robots. They adore engines, hardware the visual looks for them the smell of it, everything about it.

Such people are hardware maniac.

Comment: For those who like mechanical things like cars and motorcycles, there's _gearhead_.

Answer (score 10):

From Merriam-Webster...

> [***technophile***](http://www.yourdictionary.com/gadgeteer) *- someone who likes and enjoys technology and modern machines (such as computers)*

More informally, there's [*gadgeteer*](http://www.yourdictionary.com/gadgeteer), *gadget man, gadget freak,* etc. ([***gadget***](http://www.yourdictionary.com/gadget) *- a small, unique-use mechanical or electronic device*).

Personally, I often also use [***propeller-head***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/propeller-head) (often disparaging: *an enthusiast of technology and especially of computers*), but that may not be so common among Anglophones in general.

Comment: For me technology is the opposite of machinery. Your friend who is obssed by motorbikes and classic cars is very much not the geeky time. Tachnophile can mean the geeky iPhone type.

Answer (score 4):

[Gearhead](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gearhead) (as per Merriam Webster).  But in common usage it more accurately describes someone who wants to possess such equipment.

> : a person who is very interested in mechanical or technical things (such as cars or computers)

Another, but even more idiomatic, is **Propellerhead**.

Comment: It's a very American term though, when referring to cars the British would call them a [petrolhead](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/petrolhead)

Answer (score -2):

[Mechaphilia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanophilia) or mechanophilia:

> Mechanophilia (or Mechaphilia)[1](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanophilia) is a paraphilia involving a sexual attraction to machines such as bicycles, motor vehicles, helicoptersand aeroplanes.

Source: wikipedia.

Comment: your answers are interesting but why don't you provide relevant links for the sources you mention?

Comment: I use the mobile version of the site and using my phone, I cannot provide links or cite sources as it doesn't support any of those things. Also, I don't have a computer to access the desktop version, so I am not able to harness the full potential. I thank you for doing so. Great job and keep it up.

Comment: I think this might not be the kind of fascination the OP was talking about.